# terraform hide values that show <computed>

Tags: terraform

In terraform plan there is lots of values that show `<computed>`, e.g.:

```
aws_s3_bucket.environment-store: Creating...
  acceleration_status:         "" => "<computed>"
  acl:                         "" => "private"
  arn:                         "" => "<computed>"
  bucket:                      "" => "my-unique-bucket-1234"
  bucket_domain_name:          "" => "<computed>"
  bucket_regional_domain_name: "" => "<computed>"
  force_destroy:               "" => "false"
  hosted_zone_id:              "" => "<computed>"
  region:                      "" => "<computed>"
  request_payer:               "" => "<computed>"
  tags.%:                      "" => "2"
  tags.Environment:            "" => "env-tag"
  tags.Name:                   "" => "Storage for my environment"
  versioning.#:                "" => "1"
  versioning.0.enabled:        "" => "true"
  versioning.0.mfa_delete:     "" => "false"
  website_domain:              "" => "<computed>"
  website_endpoint:            "" => "<computed>"
```

Is there a way to not show lines that have a value of "`<computed>`", like this:

```
aws_s3_bucket.environment-store: Creating...
  acl:                         "" => "private"
  bucket:                      "" => "my-unique-bucket-1234"
  force_destroy:               "" => "false"
  tags.%:                      "" => "2"
  tags.Environment:            "" => "env-tag"
  tags.Name:                   "" => "Storage for my environment"
  versioning.#:                "" => "1"
  versioning.0.enabled:        "" => "true"
  versioning.0.mfa_delete:     "" => "false"
```

Edit: I forgot to mention that `grep -v` is not an option here - it could remove more than intended regardless of how complex the pattern is.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe it is possible to hide only a subset of the fields for a resource being created.

Per the documentation for the `terraform plan` [command](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/plan.html), you can use the `-module-depth=n` flag to control how much data is output to the console. I believe if you set `-module-depth=0` you should get no output, but I am not on my laptop to test/confirm that right now.

Comment: That would limit the output but it wont remove changed attributes that have `<computed>` as a value.

Comment: Correct. There is not an option in `terraform plan` to remove the `<computed>` values from the output. There is only the option to show all the output to a certain depth level. Your other option would be to write a script that wraps `terraform plan`. You could output the results to JSON and then remove the `<computed>` values.

Answer (score 0):

Could simply pipe the plan's stdout to `grep`'s exclusion.

```
terraform plan | grep -v ' => <computed>'
```

or even

```
$ alias tfnc="terraform plan | grep -v ' => <computed>'"
$ tfnc
```

If that's not good enough, you could install [terraform-plan-parser](https://github.com/lifeomic/terraform-plan-parser) and write a script to parse out attributes that are not `<computed>`.

Comment: Not safe as it could easily hide important messages (there's no guarantee that word isn't used in other output such as the name of a resource).

Comment: @Oliver you could use https://github.com/lifeomic/terraform-plan-parser to parse the plan into json and then remove `changedAttributes` that contain `<computed>`

Comment: Thanks @someguyonacomputer that's an interesting idea, would probably work. Although having to install node/npm and that package is not great. Would be nice if `terraform plan` had an `--out-format=json` option so that the output didn't have to be parsed.

Comment: @Oliver np. I'm surprised tf doesn't have that since it stores all of that info in json in its state. I would still go with the `grep` method as that seems to be the simpler approach and I updated the grep exclude to ensure it won't conflict with anything.

Comment: apparently the state is stored in binary format, hence the  `--out` option.